# How can I compute the number of lines of a UILabel with a fixed width?

Tags: ios, uilabel

How can I compute the number of lines of a UILabel with a fixed width and a given text ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172615/how-to-find-uilabels-number-of-lines

Comment: already tried, it's not working

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This code assumes `label` has the desired text and its frame is already set to the desired width.

```
- (int)lineCountForLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    CGSize constrain = CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:constrain lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return ceil(size.height / label.font.lineHeight);
}
```

**Update**:

If all you want is to determine the required height for the label based on its text and current width, then change this to:

```
- (CGSize)sizeForLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    CGSize constrain = CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:constrain lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return size;
}
```

The returned `size` is the proper width and height to contain the label.

Comment: Your question asked about calculating the number of lines. Are you saying you really want the required height (in points)?

Comment: as you wrote the number of lines equals the height divided by the lineHeight. I actually wanted to know the number of lines in order to compute the correct height for my label while keeping the width fixed.

Comment: constrainedToSize is deprecated since iOs 6.0

Comment: First working solution I found!

Answer (score 4):

First get the height of the label from the label size using `constrainedSize`

```
CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font 
                            constrainedToSize:label.frame.size 
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat labelHeight = labelSize.height;
```

once you have the label height then check the number of lines with the font size  where `fontsize` is the size you are using for your label. e.g it could be 10 or depending on your requirements

```
CGSize sizeOfText = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font 
                        constrainedToSize:label.frame.size 
                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
int numberOfLines = sizeOfText.height / label.font.pointSize;
```

Comment: how can I fix the width?

Answer (score -1):

You can compute the vertical height necessary to display the string using the **sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:** method on **NSString**.
Given that size, you can resize the label to display the entire string.