# Line Breaks and Number of Lines in Swift Label (Programmatically)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

By selecting a Label in a StoryBoard, I can select `Line Break` to be `Word Wrap` and change number of lines to be more than 1. How can I do that Programmatically in Swift?[image]

Comment: It is recommended to go with design-time setting since at times the run-time may not work as in my case.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can do this to set it programmatically

```
 label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
 label.numberOfLines = 3
```

Swift 3/4

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 3
```

Comment: Not much reason to set the number of lines to 1 if you want to wrap text.

Comment: I was just demonstrating how to change it.

Comment: How to do this dynamically according to text length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161348/how-can-i-compute-the-number-of-lines-of-a-uilabel-with-a-fixed-width

Comment: @rakeshbs plz look here for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723070/label-disappear-when-changing-font-size-to-25-in-swift

Comment: For resizing dynamically, refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31179855/2625761

Answer (score 27):

If you want the label to have multiple lines, do this:

```
var myLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(7, 200, 370, 100))
myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0                      //'0' means infinite number of lines
```

> *Do remember to increase the height in "CGRectMake*(7, 200, 370, **100**)"         ***<-- This***
>   
>   Otherwise the label won't be able to take the multiple lines of text.

Comment: Although I marked above as right answer because that is what I needed. This is `recommended` for auto layouts and dynamic height.

Comment: Agreed! And as much as possible, dynamic needs should be incorporated always!

Comment: Is it necessary to create the label always programatically?

Answer (score 4):

Note with **Swift 3** you need to use updated method  **byWordWrapping**

```
productNameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
productNameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
```

[image]

---

Or for adding **Ellipsis** at the end use **byTruncatingTail**

```
productNameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
productNameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
```

[image]

Comment: plz look here for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723070/label-disappear-when-changing-font-size-to-25-in-swift