# Is there a way to set a UITableView's contentInset through Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(232, 0, 232, 0)
```

is there a way of setting this in Storyboard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, UITableView is subclass of UIScrollView, its contentInset property is the property of UIScrollView, so find it in the part of UIScrollView.

[image]

For Xcode 6 updated:

[image]

I think the reason that I can set `contentInset` in Xcode 6 is because the project is created before Xcode 6. So if a project is created in Xcode 6 and above, you can't set `contentInset`. I think that is because in iOS 7 `UIViewController` will adjust this property accordingly. Look at [automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets) of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @kudosCC - the Content Insets parameters do not appear on Xcode 5 (beta 6)... any chance you know why?

Comment: @christopher.ryan.cruz My Xcode version is 5.1.1, make sure the UITableView is selected.

Comment: ah, i'm on xcode 6 actually - there seems to be a bug that hides the content inset parameters

Comment: @christopher.ryan.cruz Maybe it is a bug or this function is moved to other place. Well, I haven't downloaded Xcode 6 yet.

Comment: This section is missing from XCode 6

Comment: @JonasAlves No, it still in the Size inspector. Updated my answer for Xcode 6.

Comment: @KudoCC I insist it's not. There is only "indicator insets" there for UITableView. XCode 6.0.1

Comment: @KudoCC - not sure what's happening but I'll back up what Jonas says - It's not there! Scroll View section has Indicator Insets but NO Content Insets (xcode 6.0.1) See image at http://stackoverflow.com/q/25207927/558575 for corroboration.

Comment: Any idea why there's no content inserts anymore in XCode 7 (in IB)? How are we supposed to do this now in IB?

Comment: @lxx I think we can't do it in IB now. : (

Comment: @KudoCC I added an answer that suggests a solution for setting the content insets in the storyboard for Xcode 6+.

Comment: Still not there in Xcode 7. Lars Blumberg's answer remains the only solution within IB.

Answer (score 41):

The content inset option seems to be gone from the attribute inspector since Xcode 6. But if you don't want to define `contentInset` in code as it is user interface related, there's still an option left:

Select your `UITableView` and open the **Identity Inspector** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) and click the plus button to add an **user defined runtime attribute**. Select `Rect` as its type and `contentInset` as its key path.

See example here that changes the top inset. `50` appears to be stored as the `x` value but strangely it changes the top inset.

Reference: `{{top, left}, {bottom, right}}`

[image: Setting content inset as user defined attributed]

Comment: Good job! But look out the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @ZhouHao This question is about `UITableView`. `UILabel` doesn't support content insets natively. See here for solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437579/ios-add-left-padding-to-uilabel

Comment: Shock content  .

Comment: Has anyone any idea why Apple is so fund of removing features from their products? Correct answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

In the XIB, the UIScrollView's contentInset keypath, the values are organized in the same order as the UIEdgeInsets constructor:

`{{top, left}, {bottom, right}}`

`UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)`