# Setting a UITableView's contentInset through Storyboard in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard, xcode6

On Xcode 6, it seems that the ability to set the content inset of a scroll view/table view through UIStoryboard has been taken away. See image below:

[image: on the image]

the parameters on the left are from Xcode 6, whereas the parameters on the right are from Xcode 5

Does anyone know if the parameters have moved, or are we no longer able to set the content inset through UIStoryboard? I'd really like to keep this out of my code if possible..

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Log it with Apple.

Comment: Same issue in release version of Xcode 6.

Comment: you find anything for this? or is the only way to go with this is to do it programmatically?

Comment: @ShabarinathPabba to my knowledge, the only way is programmatic :(

Answer (score 20):

You can do that by using KVC

1. Select table view
2. Choose Identity Inspector
3. Press "+" in "User defined runtime attributes"
4. Add your inset as a Rect *{{10,15},{25,10}}* for KeyPath *contentInset*

Screenshot here:

[image]