# How to scale image UIButton to the insets?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, interface-builder

I have this `UIButton` but the insets are not on the image so the button  can be activated if the user taps outside the bounds of the image but inside the insets.

[image: UIButton]

How do I fit the image correctly using Interface Builder?

Thank you

note: with rectangular buttons works great but not rounded squared for some reason...

Comment: Try it, maybe helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207927/setting-a-uitableviews-contentinset-through-storyboard-in-xcode-6

Comment: Try following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365521/align-button-image-to-right-edge-of-uibutton?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh! I had a subtle "drop shadow" on my button style so I deactivated and now it scales good :)

Answer (score 0):

you should add the picture name in the arrow location:
[image]

Comment: hmm didn't worked, it just the image smaller made it smaller