# How to keep a space at the end of the string in ios, objective C without changing its UI(position)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have created a label programmatically.it's with is equal to the device width and I have aligned it to right.so it shows  the text from right.[image]
like this

titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

then I gave a text to the label.

```
titleLabel.text = @"Flight Summary";
```

but I want to keep a space  after **y** letter in **summary**, without decreasing the width of the label.I tried with using string format like this.

```
titleLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  ", @"Flight Summary  "];
```

but nothing happned.how can I do that.hope your help for this.thanx.

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437579/ios-add-left-padding-to-uilabel

Comment: Try changing this: titleLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flight Summary  "]; Or remove 8pts from width as titleLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width-8, height: 30)

Comment: it is not working @BharatModi, yeah I can do that by decreasing the width.I want a way without that. I have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: add padding on right side ,surely works, thats y give the sample link

Comment: You should see link provided by Anbu.Karthik's,

Comment: Add uiview with black background and inside of that view add your label with your right space.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the complexity of subclassing, you can take UIView and UIlabel, set frame of UIView to screen width and take UILabel frame as screenwidth - 8 (or whatever pixels is appropriate for you). Manage the frames and add both to mainview, this way you will be able to achieve the look.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
titleLabel.text = @"abcd exadgdf    \u{200c}""
```

You can also do one more thing. You can use attributed string and set attributed text to titlelabel without formatting string like this

```
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"ABCD      "];

titleLabel.attributedText = attrString;
```