# Ad spacing to right when adding NSTextAlignmentRight to UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I added NSTextAlignmentRight to the UILabel. I have also given border to UILabel.Now issues is there is no padding in right.

```
self.lblColumnCaption.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

[image]

Please suggest how can i add spacing to the right?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437579/ios-add-left-padding-to-uilabel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459746/adding-space-padding-to-a-uilabel

Comment: What if i don't want to subclass it

Answer (score 0):

There are so many solutions are there, but the easiset way is you can put *some space after your text*. If you don't want that please try below solution,

1. Simply add the UILabel with no background set to a UIView with the background set. Set the label's width, 10 less than the
   width of bg view.

   ```
   UIView* bg = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 70)];
   //give border and corner radius for the bg view if you want
   UILabel* yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, yourWidth-10, yourHeight)];
   [bg addSubview:yourLabel];

   [self addSubview:bg];
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can solve this by initializing your `UILabel`
   with a custom frame.

   ```
   CGRect initialFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); 
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 10); 
   CGRect paddedFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(initialFrame, contentInsets); self.label = 
   [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:paddedFrame];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers the best way is subclassing UILabel and override drawTextInRect method.

If you really don't want to override, you can use an NSAttributedString to add a right padding (tailIndent property) BEFORE setting textAlignment to NSTextAlignmentRight.

```
CGFloat rightPadding = 5.0f;
NSString *dateString = @"Your Date";

NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.tailIndent = -rightPadding;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style};

label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:dateString attributes:attributes];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this simple line of code**

```
txtFullName.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(35, 0, 0);//acc to your situation
```