# iOS: How to limit number of lines of UITextView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am making an application in which there is an UITextView that only allows users to type in 2 lines of text. So the text will not reach the third line as the UITextView would ask it to stop. Does anyone know how to approach this in Swift programming? I have found there is a way to achieve this but written in Objective-C code

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView
shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
     NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
_tempTextInputView.text = newText;

// Calcualte the number of lines with new text in temporary UITextView
CGRect endRectWithNewText = [_tempTextInputView caretRectForPosition:_tempTextInputView.endOfDocument];
CGRect beginRectWithNewText = [_tempTextInputView caretRectForPosition:_tempTextInputView.beginningOfDocument];
float beginOriginY = beginRectWithNewText.origin.y;
float endOriginY = endRectWithNewText.origin.y;
int numberOfLines = (endOriginY - beginOriginY)/textView.font.lineHeight + 1;

if (numberOfLines > maxLinesInTextView) {// Too many lines
    return NO;
}else{// Number of lines  will not over the limit
    return YES;
}

}
```

I have been struggling with the equivalent code in Swift especially this line of code:

```
NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
```

I just couldn't figure out how to deal with NSRange in Swift. Could someone please help me ?

Comment: I think this should work for that line:  NSString *newText = textView.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)

Comment: @rdelmar: what do you mean by that?

Comment: You asked how to translate that one line into Swift. That's how you do it (assuming that you've already created range and text).

Comment: @rdelmar: Your comment before being edited was confusing. But this line gives me a syntax error textView.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text) saying "nsrange is not convertible to range string.index"

Comment: I think you might have to create a variable for the textView's text (var theText = textView!.text as NSString), and use that instead of textView.text in the code I posted.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172615/how-to-find-uilabels-number-of-lines

Answer (score -1):

Can you just set the frame size for two lines and limit the total number of characters that can be entered?

Comment: That could do. But my app has multiple UITextViews so I'm afraid your approach is not quite practical in this case as I will need to count how many characters should be limited for every UITextView