# How can I know the label's numbers of line?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, label

I have a problem with my label. I am resizing the font of the label using a slider but i have to maintain the number of lines of my label. for example i have 3 lines of text when i will resize it. it must maintains 3 lines only. but in my code when I resize the font the label's number of lines is not maintaining. Thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
   float fontSize = self.sliderFont.value;

   self.lblQuotesForImg.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.lblQuotesForImg.font.fontName size:fontSize];


   [self.lblQuotesForImg setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
   self.lblQuotesForImg.numberOfLines = 0;

   [self.lblQuotesForImg sizeToFit];
```

Comment: you should use minimum font size property.it will maintain the width

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resulting lines of UILabel with UILineBreakModeWordWrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082041/resulting-lines-of-uilabel-with-uilinebreakmodewordwrap)

Comment: Change the numberoflines to 3 as shown self.lblQuotesForImg.numberOfLines = 3;

Comment: @user3205472 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172615/how-to-find-uilabels-number-of-lines see the link

Comment: when I resize the font size of label it only resize its height not the width

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code for find no of line for label

NSInteger oneLineHeight = [self findHeightForText:@"A" havingWidth:width andFont:font].height;
    NSInteger totalHeight = [self findHeightForText:txt havingWidth:width andFont:font].height;
    NSInteger noOfLines = totalHeight/oneLineHeight;

- (CGSize)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if (text) {
        //iOS 7
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font }
                                          context:nil];
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 1);
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
- (int)lineCountForText:(NSString *) text
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.lblQuotesForImg.font.fontName size:fontSize];

    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, MAXFLOAT)
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font}
                                     context:nil];

    return ceil(rect.size.height / font.lineHeight);
}
```

Hope this helps... :)